# installing maps external library on android device

Tags: android, maps

Currently I have developed an application that uses the Maps External library com.google.android.maps , it runs fine on my android phone but I bought a tablet with android and it won't install on it telling me the  [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY] error.

I have noticed that my tablet didn't come with the library pre-installed and I wonder how can I install it, the tablet has the google maps application installed but not the library to run custom maps views.

who can help me with this?

Comment: I really need some help here, anyone please?

Comment: I've been searching for the answer to this as well. Surely it's possible to include the maps lib with your app? Anybody?